# search for filenames on entire android device tree using ADB 'find'

Tags: files, search

How do I use the 'find' command on ADB to search the entire android file tree on a rooted device, including sub directories, for any filenames containing the word 'prop' ?

Comment: fHave you tried `find . -name "*prop*"`?

Comment: dang, its simple only when you know, Thank you! (used through SU shell). Anyway to output that to a text file? actually copy/paste works too lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
find . -name "*prop*"
```

- `.`: represents the current folder.
- `-name`: option to find files by name.
- `*prop*`: filenames that contain the word prop.

OR as mentioned by @alexs on the comment, you can use:

```
find . -iname "*prop*"
```

```
-iname: option to find files by name but is case insensitive.
```

If you want to find the all files with the root folder as the stating place, do as mentioned by @IrfanLatif by using:

```
find / -iname "*prop*"
```

Comment: Better use root directory explicitly (`find /`) instead of current/working dir which might not always be root dir, though by default ADB's cdir is root dir. Even better do `find /{data,system,vendor,prodct,odm}/` to avoid going through pseudo filesystems unnecessarily.

Comment: Great thanks. Id be greatful if anyone would view my XDA thread and give their 2 cents. Ill be creating this later and will post the link here in comments (if thats allowed?). Its about altering volume steps on a Lenovo M8 FHD tab (MediaTek) which Im using to replace the popular Nexus 7 (2013) for car audio head unit. Its the only tab that is exact same length as the nexus and much better spec than a galaxyTab A. Im sure the lenovo could catch on for this purpose if not for the volume problem.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/fixing-volume-steps-on-lenovo-m8-fhd-blog-car-audio.4256731/

Comment: @Mamba76 if the answer has resolved your issue, you can mark it as accepted. See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: sorry, iv learnt something new. accepted

Comment: how do i view available options / flags for shell command like 'find' ? linux use 'man' pages ect

Comment: @Mamba76 find --help

Comment: dont you just love the linux world! D